# get file api call haveing hash tag # in string not works ? C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller

I have a string

```
 http://localhost:1114/api/Upload/GetFile?uploadFile=/Uploads/SupportingDocuments/ca2432cc-a9a3-4b98-b27a-7fadf9bb524bNC%20#1%20-%20MAIL%20TO%20ACCREDITATION%20BODY%20DAC.pdf
```

The file  name have charecter hash tag '#' that I found after debugging that controller receive

```
  /Uploads/SupportingDocuments/ca2432cc-a9a3-4b98-b27a-7fadf9bb524bNC
```

as file name but if I remove this then it receive proper file name .I have a lot of documents with this file name

```
  ca2432cc-a9a3-4b98-b27a-7fadf9bb524bNC #1 - MAIL.pdf
```

So How to make api call works with this charecter also in c#

```
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetFile")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFile(string uploadFile)
    {

       //without # works only need solution
   }
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's because in a URI, `#` is the start of a [*fragment identifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It's not part of the path. If you need it as part of path (or a query parameter) you'll need to escape it as `%23`, just like you're already escaping the space as `%20`.

From [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

> As such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.

In other words, when you send a request for a URI with a fragment identifier in, the fragment identifier is stripped off, and post-processed by the browser (or whatever's sending the request) instead. So if you try to use it as part of the regular path, that's a big problem.

Comment: but why browser not doing it automatically

Comment: @noumanarshad: Because it's perfectly valid to put a `#` into a URL, as the start of the fragment identifier. But it then *isn't* included as part of the request, because it's intended for the user agent to handle. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5 for more information. (When following that link, your browser will send a request for https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 and then find the anchor for section-3.5 as the use of the fragment identifier...)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace spaces before and after `#` with `-`.
e.g. `ca2432cc-a9a3-4b98-b27a-7fadf9bb524bNC-#-MAIL-TO-ACCREDITATION-BODY-DAC.pdf`

Comment: The spaces aren't the problem - the `#` is, as it's the start of the fragment identifier in a URI.

Comment: yes, I know spaces is not the problem, but I just try to convert format identifier into url string.

Comment: I don't think I really understand your comment, but I can't see how your answer would help, given that it's still got the same problem with the `#`. Maybe it would be worth editing the answer to clarify why you'd replace the spaces, and what you think should be done with the `#`?